# Scale up math font when using eulervm package

Tags: math-fonts, scale, eulervm

Is there a way to scale up (or down) the math fonts while using `eulervm` package with respect to the text font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first try with the default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\begin{document}

Abc defg $a+b=12$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `eulervm` package provides also for a `small` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[small]{eulervm}

\begin{document}

Abc defg $a+b=12$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The option scales down the Euler fonts by 5%.

There's no direct support for any other scale factor, but you can add it yourself.

The following is exaggerated, of course, but shows the method. You can use whatever scaling factor you prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\makeatletter
\def\zeu@Scale{0.7}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Abc defg $a+b=12$

\end{document}
```

[image]